# C++ Interop behaves differently when called from windows service

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have a C# executable that makes an interop call to a C++ library:

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
public static extern int Check(string name, string version, bool debug);
```

In the C++ code, I redirect std::cout to a file:

```
std::streambuf* psbuf, * backup;
std::ofstream filestr;

...

if (debug)
{
    filestr.open("debug.txt");
    backup = std::cout.rdbuf();
    psbuf = filestr.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(psbuf);

    std::cout << "some debug message" << std::endl; 

    std::cout.rdbuf(backup);
    filestr.close();
}
```

This works fine when I run the C# executable as a console program, but when I run it as a Windows Service, the file is not created by the C++ code.

What would account for this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file actually is being created, but the working directory when running as a service is different: [as explained here](https://haacked.com/archive/2004/06/29/current-directory-for-windows-service-is-not-what-you-expect.aspx/)